# Can Core Data transient relationships point to entities in a different persistent store?

Tags: ios, core-data

I have an App that I am trying to design the data model for. I am using core data (my first App to do so).

My App will have a central database that is stored in its own persistent store as well as documents that will each be stored in their own persistent stores.

I would like to set up a transient relationship between the database and the documents, but I'm wondering if that is allowed since the database entity and the document entity will be in different persistent stores.

I know that I can achieve this by subclassing the entity and storing the documents in an NSArray or NSSet, but it would be nicer if I could use CoreData so I could take advantage of the power of searches / etc.

Thanks,
Ron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is [Fetched Properties](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/Articles/cdRelationships.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001857-SW7).